# Cannot read property 'displayDialogAsync' of undefined, microsoft/office-js-helpers

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Following the example in https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers

Here is my code:

```js
Office.initialize = () => {
    if (OfficeHelpers.Authenticator.isAuthDialog()) return;

    var authenticator = new OfficeHelpers.Authenticator();
    authenticator.endpoints.add("TW", {
        provider: 'TW',
        clientId: "twplugin",
        baseUrl: "https://auth.tw.io",
        authorizeUrl: "https://auth.tw.io/connect/authorize",
        redirectUrl: "https://localhost:3000/index.html",
        state: true,
        responseType: "id_token token",
        scope: "openid profile twapi3 allow-full-access"
    });

    authenticator
        .authenticate('TW')
        .then(function (token) {
            console.log('Success: ' + token);
        })
        .catch(OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log);
};
```

I get the following error message when attempting to get the login screen.

```
VM1930:175 TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayDialogAsync' of undefined
VM1930:187 Stack Trace
VM1930:188 TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayDialogAsync' of undefined
    at eval (eval at ../node_modules/@microsoft/office-js-helpers/dist/helpers/dialog.js (app.65ef65e66b97ddb4ec4f.js:847), <anonymous>:68:31)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Dialog._addinDialog (eval at ../node_modules/@microsoft/office-js-helpers/dist/helpers/dialog.js (app.65ef65e66b97ddb4ec4f.js:847), <anonymous>:67:16)
    at Dialog.get [as result] (eval at ../node_modules/@microsoft/office-js-helpers/dist/helpers/dialog.js (app.65ef65e66b97ddb4ec4f.js:847), <anonymous>:58:81)
    at Authenticator.eval (eval at ../node_modules/@microsoft/office-js-helpers/dist/authentication/authenticator.js (app.65ef65e66b97ddb4ec4f.js:799), <anonymous>:193:101)
    at step (eval at ../node_modules/@microsoft/office-js-helpers/dist/authentication/authenticator.js (app.65ef65e66b97ddb4ec4f.js:799), <anonymous>:43:23)
    at Object.eval [as next] (eval at ../node_modules/@microsoft/office-js-helpers/dist/authentication/authenticator.js (app.65ef65e66b97ddb4ec4f.js:799), <anonymous>:24:53)
    at eval (eval at ../node_modules/@microsoft/office-js-helpers/dist/authentication/authenticator.js (app.65ef65e66b97ddb4ec4f.js:799), <anonymous>:18:71)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (eval at ../node_modules/@microsoft/office-js-helpers/dist/authentication/authenticator.js (app.65ef65e66b97ddb4ec4f.js:799), <anonymous>:14:12)
```

It appears I did not initialize something correctly but am not sure what. I know my setting to authorize are correct, I have an simple app that does the same thing.

I also tried with this code:

```js
Office.initialize = () => {
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
        'https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins');
};
```

Received the following error:

```
main.tsx?5918:18 Uncaught TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'displayDialogAsync' of undefined
    at Object.Office.initialize (eval at ./main.tsx (app.0b7207f9d2d5e61b003a.js:4544), <anonymous>:17:27)
    at OSF_InitializationHelper$prepareRightBeforeWebExtensionInitialize [as
prepareRightBeforeWebExtensionInitialize] (o15apptofilemappingtable.debug.js:7191)
    at office.debug.js:750
    at validateFunction (office.debug.js:256)
```

Comment: Which version and build number of Outlook are you getting this on?

Comment: Outlook Client is Version 1708 (Build 8431.2079 Click to Run) The Exchange Server is 2013 not sure the build number on that or if it makes a difference, using version "@microsoft/office-js-helpers": "^0.7.4",

Comment: Host Version: 15.0.1293.4

Comment: Are you referencing a local copy of `office.js` or from the `cdn`?

Comment: Both https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js

Comment: You should only reference it once: `<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` is the correct location. If you want the debug version (although I've never needed it myself), use `https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.debug.js`

Comment: I just created a new project using VS2017 Outlook Web Add-in in the messageRead.js I pasted.  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://dev.office.com'); right above the line of code that reads $(document).ready(function () {    Put https://dev.office.com in my App Domain list and ran it same error.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to work. First because you're not referencing a page within your add-in so it doesn't have an Office.initialize(), second because it need to be a full HTTPS URL (`https://dev.office.com`). It also should go after $(document).ready so your DOM has time to load (although I don't think that is a problem here).

Comment: Also, the error you're getting here isn't actually with `displayDialogAsync`. Note that is says `'displayDialogAsync' of undefined`. If you break on that line, you should be able to determine which object isn't defined (`Office`, `context`, `ui`).

Comment: It is wrapped by the initialize, the start of VS2017 is Office.initialize then $(document) I put the line of code between the 2. Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://dev.office.com');

Comment: Entire line of code                                                                     
  Office.initialize = function (reason) {
      Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://dev.office.com');
  };

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT in my case the UI object is not defined (Office and Context are). Do you have any suggestions why could this be happening? I am building a React App for Outlook web application. My code is inside Office.initialize.

Comment: If `ui` isn't defined, I suspect your loading a local (older) version of office.js. I would start by making sure there are no references to local or debug versions of the library.